# URL variable en HTML o en Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

En `Ruby on Rails`, estoy creando un botón dentro de una tabla para que cuando lo presione, me lleve a un archivo que se encuentra en internet para descargar. El `link` lo voy a ingresar en una variable en la base de datos. La cuestión es que varía. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
<td><a href="https://www.google.com.co" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Descargar</a></td>
```

Ya probé de varias maneras, dentro de ella la siguiente y no funciona:

```
<td><a href=@url target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Descargar</a></td>
```

¿Quién me puede ayudar? De antemano, mil gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que la vista es un archivo *.erb*, el cual permite utilizar ruby dentro del mismo a través de `<% %>` y `<%= %>`; por lo tanto tu *link* se vería así:

```
<td>
  <a href="<%= @url %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Descargar
  </a>
</td>
```

Como alternativa también puedes utilizar los *helpers* de *Rails*; para *links* existe `link_to`:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to(@url, target: "_blank", class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm", role: "button" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Descargar
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Comment: Excelente @Gerry
Mil gracias!

Comment: @AlvaroAndresHernandez Espero te funcione! Y por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada (dando clic a la paloma).